# can any one give me the dry output for this program?

Tags: c

can any one give me the dry output for this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int a,b,c,d,e;
printf("Enter the Number to Find it's Reverse\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
while(a!=0)
{
b=a%10;
c=a/10;
printf("%d",b);
a=c;
}
getchar();
}
```

Comment: No. Because it will not compile.

Comment: Compiling and running it yourself is not an option?

Comment: what is getchar doing here?? whatever it be for..it will give an error since the syntax is not right. the character that is input shall be stored somewhere. 
hence it shall be like 

char e;

 e=getchar();

Comment: A lot of people put getchar(); at the end because they use Visual Studio, which last time I checked automatically closes the running window when the program ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that from dry output you mean explanation of the code, here is my attempt at it.

Suppose user enters `143`. So now `a = 143`.

```
while( a != 0 )  // a = 143 therefor condition is true and the block of
                 // code inside the loop is executed.
b =  a % 10 ;  // 143 % 10  ( The remainder is 3 )
```

So value of `b` is printed on screen

> 3

Now

```
c = a / 10 ;  // 143 / 10 =  14  
a = c ;       // so now a = 14
```

Once again, we return to the `while()`

```
while( a != 0 )  // a = 14 therefor condition is true and the block of
                 // code inside the loop is executed.
b =  a % 10 ;  // 14 % 10  ( The remainder is 4 )
```

So value of `b` is printed on screen, which already has `3`

> 34

Now

```
c = a / 10 ;  // 14 / 10 =  1
a = c ;       // so now a = 1
```

Again, we return to the `while()`

```
while( a != 0 )  // a = 1 therefor condition is true and the block of
                 // code inside the loop is executed.
b =  a % 10 ;  // 1 % 10  ( its output will be 1 )
```

So value of `b` is printed on screen which already has `34`

> 341

Now

```
c = a / 10 ;  // 1 / 10 =  0
a = c ;       // so now a = 0
```

We return to the `while()`

```
while( a != 0 )  // a = 0 therefor condition is FALSE and the block of
                 // code inside the loop is NOT executed.
```

Hope it was helpful.
**Note**
Instead of

```
c=a/10;
a=c;
```

You can simply write

```
a /= 10
```

Secondly,

```
int a,b,c,d,e;
```

What is the purpose of `e`?

Comment: tnx man it was very helpful of u

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

> Enter the Number to Find it's Reverse

:)

(*Assuming the application compiles/runs perfectly and no input is given (my interpretation of "dry")*)

Comment: @plaes: I did not write the code! ;)

Answer (score 1):

As it says itself, it waits until you enter a number then it prints the reverse. So if you enter 367 you get 763. The algorithm is quite straightforward and very popular. The % is used to get modulas of the number and 10. So you get the last digit each time. (ie. 367 % 10 is 7) and then it replaces the old number (i.e. 367) with itself divided by ten (i.e. 36) and it goes on until it gets to 0. Note: The line c=a/10; can also be replaced by a=a/10. Then the program waits (getchar()) until you press a key and then it closes. :)

Answer (score 0):

It reveres the entered number.Dry output is if you enter 123 you get 321.By the way what the variables **d** and **e** for? Remove them else your dry output will be a comiler eror LOL